# Meaning of tcp_delack_min

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

the current Linux Kernel (e.g. 2.6.36) uses Delayed Acknowledgments (delack).

In  [/include/net/tcp.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/include/net/tcp.h#L120) it says:

> define TCP_DELACK_MIN  ((unsigned)(HZ/25))

So, for a Kernel using a HZ value of 1000, an ACK should be delayed by a minimum of 40 ms.

However, RFC 2581 says a TCP implementation should acknowledge every second full sized  segment without further delay.

Does anybody know whether the Linux Kernel follows that 'should' or whether the TCP_DELACK_MIN value means that even after a full sized segment was received, the ACK continues to be delayed until 40 ms have passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched in the source code. If I read it correctly, Linux follows the SHOULD of RFC 2581.

The relevant piece of code is contained in the function  [__tcp_ack_snd_check()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L4926) in tcp_input.c.